# Get source of a function by name in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the source code of a function by using it's name in javacsript? I'm using the console and while like to see the source code of the function but can't find it. I can execute it in the console and typing only in the name returns the function object.

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically?

Comment: Look at [Function.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could achieve that by printing the function name only without invoke it

```js
function sum(x, y){
   return x + y;
}

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you log it with `console.dir`, at least in Chrome, you'll see an internal `[[FunctionLocation]]` property that's clickable. For example, Stack Exchange uses jQuery, so doing `console.dir($)` in the console shows:

[image]